# Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc) never started

Tags: service, azure-service-fabric

Same issue as [Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc) Hangs on Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364004/microsoft-service-fabric-host-service-fabrichostsvc-hangs-on-start)

Error message:
Starting service FabricHostSvc. This may take a few minutes...
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Microsoft Service Fabric Host Service (FabricHostSvc)'.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\Scripts\ClusterSetupUtilities.psm1:453 char:5
+     Start-Service FabricHostSvc -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

StartLocalCluster : Could not start FabricHostSvc
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\DevClusterSetup.ps1:73 char:1
+ StartLocalCluster
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,StartLocalCluster

Error in trace:
2017-03-31 14:52:33.311,Warning ,8388,FabricSetup.FabricSetup.FabricDeployer,Configuration Deployment failed with error 0xffffffff
2017-03-31 14:52:33.311,Error   ,8388,FabricSetup.FabricSetup.FabricSetupOperationBase,FabricDeployer::Install failed with error 0xffffffff
2017-03-31 14:52:33.311,Noise   ,8388,Timer.CancelCalled,1016010 cancel called, waitForCallbackOnCancel = false
2017-03-31 14:52:33.311,Noise   ,8388,Timer.CancelWait,1016010 wait for cancel completion
2017-03-31 14:52:33.311,Noise   ,8388,Timer.Destructed,1016010 destructed, count=0
2017-03-31 14:52:33.311,Error   ,8388,FabricSetup.FabricSetup.FabricSetupOperationExecutor,FabricDeployer::Install failed with error 0xffffffff, Rolling back

Error on starting FabricHostSvc Running windows 7 with
Service Fabric SDK 2.5.216
Service Fabric runtime 5.5.216
Visual Studio 2015 tools 1.5.50311.1

I had no issue on windows 10, is there a workaround like registry keys mentionned ? tried to enable firewall without success and look for scheduled task (none)

Comment: Few questions:Can you see if there are any logs available for FabricDeployer in your SfDevCluster logs folder? Was this a clean machine - had it had any previous SF installation? Have you tried reinstalling, or installing a previous version? Which version of Windows 7 are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the issue it was services not running RpcLocator and Firewall on local machine.

If you are running Windows 7, check if following services are started. If not start them:
RpcSs - Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
RpcLocator - Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
MpsSvc - Windows Firewall

hope it will help some other people

Comment: I was banging my head against the wall for a long time trying to fix this issue as well.  It turned out something was disabling my firewall, even after I enabled it.  Word to the wise: double check that your firewall is running, even if you've already enabled it.

Comment: Glad to hear i was not alone banging my head. Probably this is due to local or global policy which disable some services at start of session. I had also this kind of issue due to company policies, hopefully i was admin and therefore able to run script at session startup.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure "Remote Procedure Call", "Remote Procedure Call Locator" services are up and running, I also had to physically create "ImageStoreShare" folder @ "c:\SfDevCluster\Data" folder, since it was failing to create the folder due to permission issue.